# How to catch error when there is on duplicate key?

Tags: php

I wants to check if there is an error for a column(username) which has been set as Unique Index. On my research I have founded that Mysqli generated duplicate key error. I don't know how to catch that error. One way I can think is that to check db if dp has that value and then just manually generate some sort of error. and just show it at appropriate place. 
Any Help here? i wants to Prepare Statement.

Comment: Provide the sample code for your question

Comment: Either do your Pre Check query or look at the error code returned by [`mysqli_errno`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php)

Comment: @SASSY_ROG there isn't any 
Since to me its pretty simple
How do catch an error if there is an duplication for a column set with Unique Index.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  
That simple? 
No special way to check if there is an error generated specifically by that condition?

Comment: No, just look for the relevant error code or codes

Comment: Of course if the site is well designed, this situation should never happen, cant remember ever having this issue or needing to code around it

Comment: @RiggsFolly so how do you guyz design such system? As you can judge, I am new to this type of thing.

Comment: Now that is a HUGE question :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly tutorial of some sort can be shared. I can ask a new question and paste url here. We can go into personal discussion. :) 
Anything would work. perhaps some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better query your table before inserting new entry and check if there is already something:

```
if (!$db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `username` = {$username}")) {
     $db->query("INSERT INTO `table` (`username`) VALUES ('{$username}')")
} else {
     //print or return error 
}
```

as for me it's not good to run query that returns duplicate error and then trying to parse error code returned, although it seems possible

Comment: Why?
What's wrong with mysqli_error() ?